# Continuous touchListener (Piano like interface)

Tags: android

So I am trying to implement a piano like interface but with textviews instead of keys. When I slide from textView to `textView` it should trigger something. I tried using an `onTouchListener` instead of an `onClickListener`, but it doesn't seem to work. It only triggers the first textView that I touch. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 tv.setOnTouchListener(new CustomTouchListener());

public class CustomTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {     
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch(motionEvent.getAction()){            
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Action you you want on finger down.
  Toast.makeText(this,"onTouch",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;          
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:             
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Action you you want on finger up
                break;
    } 
        return false;   
    } 
}
```

Is this exact what you need?? Please share some code of you which will make more easier to fix problem.